# jest.ts and got.ts giving "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, node.js-got

I'm new to Typescript, jest.ts, and got.ts - I'm trying to create an API test, but I'm getting an

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.  I've tried several fixes but failed on all of them.

Package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/got": "^9.6.12",
    "got": "^12.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test-gotjest": "npx jest ./tests/gotjest"
  }
}
```

jest.config.js

```
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["@testing-library/jest-dom"]
};
```

the actual test file itself - gotjest.test.ts

```
import { got } from "got";
import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals';

  describe('see if got works', () => {
    test('get a cat fact', () => {
    let foo = got.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact');
          expect(3).toBe(3);
    });
  });
```

when I run the test with "npm run test-gotjest" I get the following:

```
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import { got } from "got";
        | ^
      2 | import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals';
      3 |
      4 | describe('sum module', () => {

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1678:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/gotjest/gotjest.test.ts:1:1)
```

What am I missing?
When I run with out got, the import statement for

```
import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals';
```

works fine.   Help!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution mentioned in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/issues/1952

TL:DR; downgrade to got v11 to interop with jest.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33252746)